# camel route http response xml parsing

Tags: java, xml, http, apache-camel

I am new to using camel and I need to build a route in JAVA to process some xml returned by http request. I tried to parse the body of the response by setting up a route with a processor and log it to a file setting the consumer as http url but it didn't work. Then I tried to set up a jms queue to grab and process it from the queue with similar result. 
I think I am getting the 200 response but the producer text file I set it to write to is not working and the log4j in DEBUG is not too informative on isolating the issue. Does anyone have any insight on this issue to point me in the right camel direction? thanks in advance!

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    // connect to embedded ActiveMQ JMS broker
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = 
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");
    camelContext.addComponent("jms",
            JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
    try {
        camelContext.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                .to("http://tomcatappurl:8080/format=xml?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                 .process(new OrderProcessor())
                 .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                 .log("file:C:/Desktop/camellog1.txt")
                 .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                 .log("${headers}")
                 .convertBodyTo(String.class)
                 .to("file:C:/Desktop/camellog1.txt")
                 .log("${in.headers}")
                 .to("stream:out")
                 .to("jms");


                from("jms:incomingOrders")
                 .process(new Processor() {
                     public void process (Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                         //HttpServletRequest request = exchange.getIn().getBody(HttpServletRequest.class);
                            System.out.println("Response received from Google, is streamCaching = " + exchange.getContext().isStreamCaching());
                            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------IN MESSAGE--------------------------------------------------------------");
                            System.out.println(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class));
                            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------OUT MESSAGE--------------------------------------------------------------");
                            //System.out.println(exchange.getOut().getBody(String.class)); //Activating this line causes empty response on browser

                        }
                    })
                .to("file:C:/Users/Desktop/camellog1.txt?fileExist=Append");
            }
        });
        camelContext.start();
    } finally {
        camelContext.stop();
    }


}
```

Comment: Set up and Error handler on your routes, this way you make sure there are no silent exceptions happening..I had occasions when dealing with Camel routes where Exceptions were being thrown, but not caught anywhere

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/error-handler.html ^^

Comment: So what exactly is the error? Is the file not being written? Bad content? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think your routes are not running.

You need something (like a [timer](http://camel.apache.org/timer.html)) to trigger your routes, for example:

```
from("timer:myTimer?period=30s")
    .to("direct:start");
```

Camel [documentation for Direct component](http://camel.apache.org/direct.html) says:

> The **direct:** component provides direct, synchronous invocation of any consumers when a producer sends a message exchange.

So you need something else to start the invocation of the route.

Mind that your first route must finish to the correct JMS queue:

```
// ... cut
.to("file:C:/Desktop/camellog1.txt")
.log("${in.headers}")
.to("stream:out")
.to("jms:incomingOrders");
```

without the queue name it will not work.